# Running ASP.NET WebAPI Project in Debug After Published

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-debugging

I have published my Visual Studio ASP.NET WebAPI project and have since realized that I would like to make changes to it. When I press F5 and try to run my project locally it now won't let me do it and I get an error that simply reads "Can't Reach This Page". It would be very useful to be able to set break points and check variables at this point in development so I need the debugger. How can I make it so I can debug my project again?

Answer (score -1):

> Running ASP.NET WebAPI Project in Debug After Published

Have you publish your ASP.NET WebAPI Project to the Remote IIS server? If yes, you can install and run the remote tools on the computer where you deployed your app, and then attach to your running app from Visual Studio.

Document: [Remote Debug ASP.NET on a Remote IIS Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue when using someone else's sample project.  Leo, you answer is not relevant ... the poster clearly statues "run my project locally" and you replied by telling him to do a remote Debug session on an IIS computer???

Comment: Same here. I published my `webapi` project on Azure and after that i cant debug my app in localhost (i added new controller because i need it). How can i Debug it on my local machine? Or how can i have acces to `Azure Web App` machine from service?